# Load children dynamically using Grails Fixture plugin

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to load data in a Grails application using the Fixture plugin.

```
class Author {
  String name 
}

class Book {
  String title
  hasMany = [authors:Author]
}
```

I load Author in a separate file and include it in the Book one.

```
//author fixture
fixture {
  author1(Author) {
    name = 'Ken Follett'
  }
  author2(Author) {
    name = 'Martin Fowler'
  }
}

//book fixture
fixture {
  include 'author'
  "book"(Book) {
    title = 'Your favorite book'
    authors = [author1, author2]
  }
}
```

This all works fine. What I can't do, is to replace [author1, author2] so I can dynamically (and randomly) assign authors. Something like:

```
def dynamicallyBuiltAuthorList = "author1, author2, author100"
authors = ["${dynamicallyBuiltAuthorList}"]
```

Pretty much everything I tried so far gave me a no matching editors or conversion strategy found error.

Thanks in advance Grails gurus!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer below (and the previous edit to this answer), this is probably a better way:

```
def dynamicallyBuiltAuthorList = [ 'author1', 'author2', 'author100' ].collect {
  ref( "$it" )
}
authors = dynamicallyBuiltAuthorList
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, great insight, in the end the exact answer is similar, just replace the `this."$it"` by `anotherList.add(ref("$it"))` and that worked out.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer is simply:

```
def authorList = []
def dynamicallyBuiltAuthorList = [ 'author1', 'author2', 'author100' ].collect {
   authorList.add(ref("$it"))
}
authors = authorList
```

Thanks to Tim for the help!

Comment: Updated my answer based on this.  If you are doing `collect`, you don't need a secondary list to add to :-)